# How to put "click to enlarge" images in PDFs?

Tags: pdf, pictures

I am creating a company newsletter in Publisher and saving as a PDF.  Can you place an image in a PDF file and give readers of the PDF the ability to click on the image and it enlarges?

Comment: Add hidden pages, link the image there?